# JavaScript Redirect Keeps Adding To Path

Tags: javascript, redirect

I'm using the following JavaScript code to redirect mobile users:

```
<script>
var reg = "website.co.uk/folder";
var mob = "folder.website.co.uk";

if(window.innerWidth >= 960) {
   if(window.location.hostname != reg)
      window.location.replace("http://" + reg + window.location.pathname + window.location.search)
}
else {
   if(window.location.hostname != mob)
      window.location.replace("http://" + mob + window.location.pathname + window.location.search)
}
</script>
```

This is working fine in my localhost but when I upload and test it ( Full sized screen ) redirects me to:

> website.co.uk/folder/folder

Any ideas why?

Comment: @SterlingArcher My mistake - I meant Javascript

Comment: Happens! Instead of `.replace` try setting it to `window.location.href` instead

Comment: Ok, that has stopped the error, however now it won't redirect to mobile site when the screen is shrunk down